# dotnet core change swagger.json server url wrong under subdir

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have a dotnet core webapi project that is setup with swagger.

Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSwaggerGen();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "myapi.Api V1");
    });
}
```

Controllers are like so:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Policy = "policyname")]
public class ThingController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetThing()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

This works fine locally and once deployed to the server and accessed directly (eg https://myservername/myapi/swagger/index.html can correctly make api calls to https://myservername/myapi/api/thing)

However we have an alias setup to access via https://myapp.company.com/services/myapi.

Now making direct api calls works eg https://myapp.company.com/services/myapi/api/thing returns the same as https://myservername/myapi/api/thing

Swagger UI displays correctly at https://myapp.company.com/services/myapi/swagger/index.html and it is loading swagger.json correctly but all api calls are made as https://myapp.company.com/myapi/api/thing i.e.. /services is missing from the api base url, needless to say these api calls fail.

Swagger.json contains the following:

```json
 "servers": [
    {
      "url": "/myapi"
    }
  ],
```

I presume this should be /services/myapi and the rest should fall into place. How can I set this?

I've done some googleing and found plenty of questions asking how to move swagger ui to a new location (UseSwaggerUI(c => c.RoutePrefix) and some on how to move swagger.json to a new location (app.UseSwagger(c => c.RouteTemplate) but neither of them is what I want.

How can I configure swagger's server url at runtime? Preferably using local paths so it works on all environments (eg it 'just knows' its at https://myservername/myapi/, https://myapp.company.com/services/myapi/ or even https://localhost:5001/ and sets the base url as appropriate.)

Comment: Does setting the base path help ? (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/). i.e., serviceBasePath in nswag.json

Comment: @Subbu Sounds like it would help, what is nswag? Does it replace swashbuckle?

Comment: I have assumed you were already using NSwag (https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag). The nswag.json is the normal settings file for NSwag.

Comment: added missing tag, sorry for confusion